# Win32 or x86 for Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, x86

What is the difference between those project platforms in Visual Studio ? Which one should I use for Windows Phone app? I read a few articles but it go me just more confused.

Currently I am using Win32 for emulator, and ARM for the device.

Comment: They mean the exact same thing.  "Win32" is the legacy name for 32-bit projects, it made sense 20 years ago.  Back when everybody stopped creating Win16 programs.  Microsoft has been trying to get rid of it, substituting x86 instead.  Not that easy when the term has been used by programmers for that long.  VS2015 gets it almost right.

Comment: So I should use x86 in my project?

Comment: Flip a coin.  If it lands on the same side as your existing project then you don't have to do anything.  If it doesn't then flip again.

Comment: Love that answer, thank You !